# C++ map of string as key and type as value

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-mpl, boost-fusion, boost-hana

Is there an alternative to [boost-hana](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/hana/doc/html/index.html) in boost library which will allow me to create something like

```
typedef boost::AlterinativeToHana::map< make_pair<"abcd",ABCDType>,
                 make_pair<"efgh",EFGHType>,
                 make_pair<"ijkl",IJKLType>
               > stringToTypeMap;
```

I have used [boost-fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/index.html), but I could not find a proper solution for my use case i.e character string to type mapping.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need an alternative to Hana?

Comment: @LouisDionne... My workplace's platform compilers are still using Boost 1.56 and dont plan to upgrade it till early 2018.

Comment: Ah, ok. If you are using a modern compiler (probably not the case if you use the platform's compiler), however, you can also install Hana only without having to update your Boost distribution.

Comment: @LouisDionne... Ahh, I think I created some confusion there. When I said platform, I meant OS's (`Win, OS-X and Linux`) all the modern 64 bit compilers. For Linux/OS-X we compile with `--std=c++11` switch and we dont plan to upgrade it to use C++14 any-time soon. So even if I do decide to use Hana, I might not be able to use its full functionality as the compiler requirements for Hana suggest that it needs C++14 compilers.

Comment: Ok. Hana will definitely not work without -std=c++14.

Comment: Are you trying to map run-time string values to types or will the string values always be known at compile-time?

Comment: Strings will be known at compile time.

Answer (score 6):

I think [std::type_index](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) is what you need:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeindex>
#include <map>

class A
{};

class B
{};

int main()
{   
    std::map<std::type_index, std::string> typesMap;
    typesMap[typeid(A)] = "1111";
    typesMap[typeid(B)] = "2222";

    A instA;
    B instB;

    cout << "instA: " << typesMap[typeid(instA)] << "\n";
    cout << "instB: " << typesMap[typeid(instB)] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
instA: 1111
instB: 2222
```

Comment: I actually needed the reverse mapping here as opposed to what you have mentioned. From `std::string` to a well defined type.

Comment: As you understand it is no problem to make `std::map<std::string, std::type_index>`. I made this `type->string` mapping because this example is easier to understand. In real life you will need something more conneted with `std::type_info` like `construction functions`.