# C++: can I get a "generic" (non-template) pointer (or reference) to a template class?

Tags: c++

I have the following problem:

- I have a class template where each instance represents an array of values (type of values is the template argument, of course).
- each instance has a name and that name is stored in the instance itself and in a `static std::map`

Something along the lines:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <map>

template <class T> class block {
private:
    T           *ptr;
    std::string name;
    std::size_t size;

    static std::map<std::string, block<T>&>    blocks;
public:
    block(std::string _name, T *_ptr, std::size_t _size)
    : name(_name)
    , ptr(_ptr)
    , size(_size)
    {
        blocks[_name] = this;
    }
    
    virtual ~block() {}

    static block<T> &find(std::string key) {
        return blocks[key];
    }
};
```

Now I have the following problem:

write a function that, given the block name, an index and a `unsigned char []`, should fill a single element element in the right block taking as many bytes "as needed".

Signature of such a function (or member) should be something like:

```
void set_element(std::string block_name, int index, void *source);
```

Is there a clean way to do this?

Ideally the only prerequisite should be there actually are enough bytes in the pointed array (I can add a `std::size_t available_bytes` to function signature to actually check and `throw` an error if there aren't enough bytes available).

If useful: reason why I need this is the I receive "unstructured" data from network and that's a byte stream I need to parse piece by piece.

To be more precise: the input stream i get is composed by a sequence of:

- a "C string" (null-terminated) representing the block name
- a single byte representing the index (0..255)
- "element" binary representation

There may be multiple "blocks" stick back-to-back in the input stream so it would be useful to have a return value stating either the number of bytes used or a pointer to first unused.

It's assumed binary data it comes from a compatible architecture and thus it is a correct representation.

The block name implicitly gives the size and characteristics of the element.

Incoming data is not supposed to be aligned; OTOH array pointed in block::ptr is supposed to be correctly aligned so I can access it with normal pointer arithmetic.

Note: the above example code is **not** good because it will produce separate `blocks` for different template arguments while I need all names to be thrown in the same bag; I assume I will need to implement a parent class, but it's unclear exactly how to do it: I will update if I come to it.

Comment: Getting your usage of terminology straight is perhaps already half an answer. You can get a pointer to an instance of some type. The type can be an instantiation of a class template (there are no template classes). You cannot get a pointer to a template.

Comment: How do you know which type the block has given `block_name`, `index` and `source`? Btw: there's one more thing you need to consider: alignment.

Comment: @fabian: I get a stream that's composed by a "C string" (null-terminated) representing the block name, immediately followed by a single byte representing the index (0..255) immediately followed by the "element" binary representation (it's assumed it comes from a compatible architecture). The name of the block implicitly gives the size and characteristics of the element. Incoming data is not supposed to be aligned; array pointed in block::ptr is supposed to be correctly aligned so I can access it with normal pointer arithmetic. I will update OP to reflect and clarify.

Comment: `block<foo>` and `block<bar>` are different, unrelated classes, so you cannot have a "generic" pointer to them, unless you are fine with C-style `void*`. Either you also use a template to `void set_element(...)`, possibly with some [types mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37641427/c-map-of-string-as-key-and-type-as-value), or just create a parent class `class AbstractBlock` and make other blocks (still possibly templated) derive from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the exercise of deriving from a base class.

Here is a piece of code actually compiling:

```
#ifndef AWBLOCK_H_
#define AWBLOCK_H_

#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <map>

namespace AW {

class generic_block {
private:
    static std::map<std::string, generic_block*>    blocks;

protected:
    std::string name;
    std::size_t size;

    virtual int _set(int, void *) = 0;

public:
    generic_block(std::string _name, std::size_t _size)
    : name(_name)
    , size(_size)
    {
        blocks[_name] = this;
    }

    virtual ~generic_block() {}

    static generic_block *find(std::string key) {
        return blocks[key];
    }

    void *set(std::string _name, int _index, void *data) {
        if (blocks.find(_name) == blocks.end()) {
            throw std::invalid_argument("Unknown block '"+_name+"'");
        }
        if (_index >= (int)size) {
            throw std::out_of_range("Index "+std::to_string(_index)+" exceeds size of block '"+_name+"' ("+std::to_string(size)+")");
        }
        int n = blocks[_name]->_set(_index, data);
        return ((char *)data)+n;
    }

    virtual int count(void) {
        return size;
    }
};

template <class T> class AWblock: public generic_block {
private:
    T           *ptr;

public:
    AWblock(std::string _name, T *_ptr, std::size_t _size)
    : generic_block(_name, _size)
    , ptr(_ptr)
    {
    }

    virtual ~AWblock() {}

    int _set(int _index, void *_data) {
        int n = sizeof(*ptr);
        memcpy(ptr+_index, _data, n);
        return n;
    }
};

} /* namespace AW */

#endif /* AWBLOCK_H_ */
```

Minimal test program:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

#include "AWblock.h"

#define countof(__) (sizeof(__)/sizeof(__[0]))

namespace AW {

std::map<std::string, generic_block*>    generic_block::blocks;

int int_block[22];
AWblock<int32_t> _int_block("int-block", int_block, countof(int_block));

TEST(AWblock, HandleCount) {
    EXPECT_EQ(_int_block.count(), 22);
}

} /* namespace AW */
```

apparently works fine:

```
Running main() from /usr/src/googletest/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from AWblock
[ RUN      ] AWblock.HandleCount
[       OK ] AWblock.HandleCount (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from AWblock (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

If there's a better approach I will gladly accept it, otherwise I will accept my own answer in a few days.