# how to map a class object and instantiate it

Tags: c++

I'm trying to mimic this Python functionality:

```
class Bla:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

{"bla": Bla}["bla"](None) # create a Bla class dynamically
```

I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37641427/c-map-of-string-as-key-and-type-as-value) but it didn't help me...

My C++ module looks something like this:

```
// MyObj is an abstract class with all its subclasses using same signature constructor
class Factory{
  MyObj create_obj(int n);
}

std::map<std::string, MyObj> my_map = {"example1", MyObj1};
my_map["example1"](0);
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: `my_map["example2"]` will automagically create a default -constructed `MyObj` and map it to `"example2"`. It won't work with `"example1"`, because `"example1"` already exists in the map. If you want t make use of the factory, that's a bit more work.

Comment: C++ lacks the ability to create object given the name of the class. This ability is sometimes called *reflection*, many languages have it, but C++ does not. It's impossible in C++ because the classes that exist in your source code no longer exist in the compiled code, so you can't use a string to lookup a class automatically. You have to do that lookup yourself.

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do. Object factories generally do not look like that. They involve **polymorphic objects**, and some kind of mapping between class names and **functions** or a function objects. Each function should create an objects of a given class and return a **pointer**  to that object. A map that maps strings to regular (non-function) objects is not essential to a factory interface.

Comment: *"I'm trying to mimic this Python functionality"* -- this immediately limits you potential audience to people who know both Python and C++. In contrast, if you were to write out a description of the functionality you desire (possibly using the Python code as an illustration), then you open up the question to people who know C++ but not Python.

Comment: @JaMiT true - but I feel my motivation, and case's nuances will be more understandable to people knowing Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++, in contrast to Python, is statically typed. Classes are not first-class objects and you can't store them.

In the following I assume that `MyObj` is the abstract base that all "stored" types are meant to inherit from and that `MyObj1`/`MyObj2` are some of these types.

Instead of the classes themselves, you can store function pointers or `std::function`s which return a `std::unique_ptr<MyObj>` pointing to a newly-created object of the corresponding type, so that `my_map["example1"](0);` has a well-defined static type. For example:

```
#include<functional>  // for std::function
#include<memory>      // for std::unique_ptr and std::make_unique
#include<type_traits> // for std::has_virtual_destructor_v

//...

template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<MyObj> MakeMyObj(int n) {
    static_assert(std::has_virtual_destructor_v<MyObj>);
    return std::make_unique<T>(n);
}

// or std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<MyObj>(*)(int)>
std::map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<MyObj>(int)>> my_map = {
    { "example1", MakeMyObj<MyObj1> },
    { "example2", MakeMyObj<MyObj2> }
};

//...

auto x = my_map["example1"](0); // x has type std::unique_ptr<MyObj>
auto y = my_map["example2"](123); // y also has type std::unique_ptr<MyObj>
```

`std::function` supports more types of callables than a function pointer approach would, but has significantly more runtime overhead. With the function pointer approach, trying to use an unassigned string argument will also result in undefined behavior, while the `std::function` approach will throw an exception.

As mentioned in the other answer, a more straight-forward approach if you don't need to modify the map at runtime is to write a single factory function or class which directly switches on string arguments and throws an appropriate exception directly.

In any case it is important that this requires that `MyObj` has a `virtual` destructor. Otherwise the program will have undefined behavior. That is what the `static_assert` is meant to protect against, since `std::unique_ptr` itself currently unfortunately doesn't verify that.

Answer (score 2):

An object factory normally looks like this (most non-essential details omitted).

```
class Animal { virtual ~Animal() = default; }
class Dog : public Animal {};
class Cat : public Animal {};

class AnimalFactory
{
   public:
     std::unique_ptr<Animal> make(std::string kind) {
       if (kind == "cat") return std::make_unique<Cat>();
       if (kind == "dog") return std::make_unique<Dog>();
       throw FactoryException("Unsupported animal");
     }
};
```

Now you can, instead of `if-else` in `make`, use a map. But this is an implementation detail.

```
class AnimalFactory
{
      using fn = std::function<std::unique_ptr<Animal>()>;
      std::map<std::string, fn> make_map = std::map<std::string, fn> {
          {"cat", []() { return std::make_unique<Cat>(); }},
          {"dog", []() { return std::make_unique<Dog>(); }}
      };    
    public:
      std::unique_ptr<Animal> make(std::string kind) {
          auto fn = make_map.find(kind);
          if (fn != make_map.end()) return fn->second();
          else throw FactoryError("Unsupported animal");
      }

};
```

Things to note:

1. Objects made by the factory are polymorphic. (Otherwise there usually isn't a lot of sense in having a factory.)
2. Objects are returned by pointer to their base class.
3. The map, if any, maps strings to functions that make objects.

Comment: shouldn't factory implement static `"make"`? I thought it is better to not create a factory object

Comment: @CIsForCookies there are different approaches to this. There is nothing inherently wrong with a factory object. It can itself be polymorphic with `make` being a virtual function. See AbstractFactory design pattern. But if you want to make it static no one is stopping you either.